# How to redirect all subdirectories to the domain's root?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain with multiple domains parked on it.
What I need to do is to redirect every traffic from subdirectories to root path.
for example my domain is `example.com` when the visitor lands on a subdirectory I want him to be redirected to the root. like this:

```
http://example.com/foo ==> http://example.com
```

and also consider the part about parked domains.

```
http://bar.com/foo == > http://bar.com (parked on example.com)
```

Comment: do you want to redirect all requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it's done like this:

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)(.*)$     / [R]
```

Special thanks to `Death`.

Comment: this just breaks the page, the page won't redirect correctly

Answer (score 3):

this rewrite rule  rewrites all requests from sub-directory to one level-up(root).

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)\/(.*)$     $2 [L]
```

Comment: thank you. although your answer actually was not what I wanted, but somehow with your help I managed to do it. thanks